# Kafka doesn't let me delete consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to delete consumer groups in kafka 10.2.1:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper myzkhost --list
consumer-1
consumer-2
...
consumer-n
```

if i do:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper myzkhost --delete --group consumer-1
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

Error: Delete for group 'consumer-1' failed because group does not exist.
```

but when i go to my zookeeper host:

```
ls /consumers/consumer-1
[offset]
```

and that happens with all consumers... is it safe to delete the zookeeper path for those consumers?

Thanks!

Comment: It's weird why `ids` znode was removed in your case. Kafka checks the existence of child znodes under this znode to see if the to-be-deleted group is inactive. In your case, Kafka threw ZkNoNodeException before successfully deleting group. You could run `create /consumers/consumer-1/ids ""` in Zookeeper and retry the command to bypass this issue.

Comment: ok, i'll try to do it, do i need to put anything under ids (like the broker ids) or it wouldn't matter? thanks

Comment: The existence of that znode matters, what's in it doesn't.

Comment: i haven't had time to check it yet, i will get back to you as soon as i do it :)